# Why does this not show $P(A\cup B) \subseteq P(A)\cup P(B)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know that this is false but why does this not work:
Suppose $X\in P(A\cup B)$. Then
$$X \subseteq A\cup B \\ X \subseteq A \quad \text{or} \quad X\subseteq B \\
X\in P(A) \quad \text{or}\quad X\in P(B) \\ X\in P(A)\cup P(B)
$$

Comment: "$X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$"  does not follow from $X\subseteq A\cup B.$ What makes you think it does?

Comment: X is a set, not an individual element, some of the elements of X may be in A, and some may be in B.  There's no reason to assume being a subset is all or nothing.  Example if A={1,2,3,4,5} and B={a,b,c,d,e}.  Then {1,a} is a subset of A union B but it isn't a subset of either A or B.  (You can say that there do exist two $C,D $ so that $X=C\cup D $ and $C\subset A $ and $D\subset B $.  But that's not relevent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From $X\subseteq A\cup B$ we cannot deduce $X\subseteq A$ or $X\subseteq B$, take for example $A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{a,b,c\}$ and $X=\{1,a\}$, where $a,b,c,1,2,3$ are all pairwise distinct.

Answer (score 2):

$X\subseteq (A\cup B)\not\Rightarrow (X\subseteq A) ~\vee  (X\subseteq B)$. So second step in your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Take $A = \{a\}$, $B=\{b\}$ and $X = \{a,b\}$...